# Strange transactions that get all balance from account on test network

Tags: rinkeby

I am writing smart contract and I test on rinkeby network. I have issued about 18 ethereums from faucet. But after a short time, there are 2 strange transactions: one getting 15eth and one getting 3eth from my account. Here is transaction detail:

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xc4829a6c8765a11c364abfe4370bfc5c42db8f4f30a750185249cd423a836242

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x6123a4af9dfd7eb06bab18bef5b0db729bfefe49df09710dcac8fab52127a08c

My address is: `0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57`. You can view my transaction detail here (from the time I issue 18eth):
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x627306090abab3a6e1400e9345bc60c78a8bef57

So, what is my problem here ? I afraid if "something wrong" and I don't know, I will lost more money on main network.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/686.

It looks like you used a well-known private key that's generated from a development tool called Truffle.

Because everyone already knows the private key, anyone can take ether put into that account.

If you need to know more, Google "0x627306090abaB3A6e1400e9345bC60c78a8BEf57" to find plenty of other discussion, e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/7j8l5b/warning_i_sent_eth_to_my_metamask_account/?st=jidk6be8&sh=02499a0e.